# Address Unification

Tags: forms, search, logic, delimiter

I'm creating a business directory where I need to display results based on area and keywords. The problem is the scope might be across countries that have fairly irregular address structures. I currently have the following as form fields (and their respective database fields)

Fields (All required):
- Address 1 
- Address 2 
- Area <------key search criteria 
- Keywords <------key search criteria

The problem is I'm not sure how reliable this setup is. I would have to rely on the data entry when searching to be relevant enough for it to work, and that goes against validating everything before inserting to the database. Is there a standard way of looking up areas across countries? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to solve this by running (and verify) addresses via batch geocoding, which converts the addresses to 'geocodes' one can use with mapping plugins (there seems to be a lot of solutions in this regard. Google "batch geocode addresses"), although you may have to research further for accuracy. Though I initially started with OpenLayers for mapping I found leaflet faster to understand and deploy (with emphasis on mobile), Though I am talking from my own experience of learning and being able to implement in time.